# Default charset for file encoding - Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

For the below program,

```
package io.buffer;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TestCharSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Print the default Charset
        System.out.println("The default charset is: " + Charset.defaultCharset());

    }

}
```

---

The default charset for file encoding is kept in the system property `file.encoding`. To change the JVM's default charset for file encoding, you can use command-line VM option `-Dfile.encoding`.

Program with arguments:

```
> java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 TestCharSet
```

gives output:

```
The default charset is: UTF-8
```

Program with arguments:

```
> java -Dfile.encoding=ascii TestCharSet
```

gives output:

```
The default charset is: US-ASCII
```

---

Why `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-16 TestCharSet` gives output `��`?

Comment: Is that the entire output? Just those two characters?

Comment: @TedHopp Yes. entire output is just those two characters

Comment: Look at it this way, there three program runs from a shell/terminal/prompt, each directing the program to output using a different encoding. Assuming the encoding of the shell is kept the same, at least two—maybe all—of the runs are wrong. Now, if you pipe the output to a file as @TedHopp suggests, they are all right because each produces a text file that you know the encoding for. (The big question is: why would you mess with the default encoding, anyway?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your program on my Mac with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-16`, I get the following output (as a hex dump):

```
0000000    fe  ff  00  54  00  68  00  65  00  20  00  64  00  65  00  66
0000020    00  61  00  75  00  6c  00  74  00  20  00  63  00  68  00  61
0000040    00  72  00  73  00  65  00  74  00  20  00  69  00  73  00  3a
0000060    00  20  00  55  00  54  00  46  00  2d  00  31  00  36  00  0a
```

So what is probably happening with you is: setting `file.encoding` to UTF-16 causes Java to write UTF-16 sequences to the console and your console is not set up to handle UTF-16 output. The first two bytes (which together form the Unicode [BYTE ORDER MARK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) don't display properly (probably due to your console font and/or driver) and the remaining output is truncated at the first null byte (again, due to your console software).

You can try directing the output of your program to a file and looking at it with a hex editor or something too get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: `fe  ff` is BOM marker.Am using Eclipse IDE console. On terminal, Am not able to run the code`~/eclipse-workspace/IO/src/io/buffer$ java -classpath . TestCharSet` because it gives output `Error: Could not find or load main class TestCharSet`

Comment: @overexchange - I think I said that. ("BOM" is an acronym for "byte order mark".) As for the error, get rid of the `package` declaration from OP's code if you want to run this from the command line, or else put the `.class` file in a folder `./io/buffer` and use the command line `java -classpath . io.buffer.TestCharSet`.

Comment: @overexchange  - Yes, but not from the subfolder `io/buffer`. Java will be looking for a subfolder `io/buffer` from some folder on the class path. If your current directory is the subfolder and you use `-classpath .`, it won't find it. Perhaps if you're in `io/buffer` to start with you could use `-cp ../..`. I haven't tried that.

Comment: Being in `../IO/src/io/buffer` and placing `.class` in `./io/buffer` and running `java -classpath . io.buffer.TestCharSet` gives same error

Comment: @overexchange - Well, there's some path problem. Just get rid of the `package` line and it should run fine.